# How to use url_for to read a file in templates folder?

Tags: python, flask

I tried to read file `print.html` that located in path: `templates/print.html`.

So, I used `url_for()` to refer to it as below:

```
{{ url_for('templates', filename='print.html') }}
```

However, I got an error as below Traceback:

> BuildError: ('templates', {'filename': 'print.html'}, None)

What's wrong with this?

If I used `{{ url_for('static', filename='print.html') }}`, it just working find. However, file that I tried to read is not in `static` folder, it was in `templates/print.html` instead.

How can I use `url_for()` to read my file `print.html` in `templates` folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll start by saying-- if you're trying to `url_for` a template, it's likely you're misunderstanding a concept. But, assuming you're know the difference between a rendered template and a static asset:

You could build a route for the `print.html`:

```
@app.route('/print')
def print():
    return render_template('print.html')
```

Which would then enable you to `url_for('print')` to get the resolved url, and any dynamic components in your `print.html` template would get rendered to static html.

Otherwise, if the `print.html` is truly static-- just move it to the `static` folder, and use the `url_for('static', filename='print.html')` as you've indicated.

There's a handy Flask blueprint pattern that's useful if you're just rendering off a bunch of templates and don't need any view logic, [see it here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#my-first-blueprint)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. By the way, `return render_template('print.html')` would render template `print.html` directly on browser, yet I am trying to read content of `print.html` that would include `html` tags as well. Reason I put it in templates folder, because `print.html` contain some `macro` definitions that it is called to use in another template, `{% from "print.html" import any_macro %}`. Thanks.